# Como Importar classes de outro package

Tags: ruby, importação

Como faço para importar uma classe que está em outro pacote
Exemplo: pacote "modelo" contém a classe "Carro", pacote "execucao" contém a classe "Main", de dentro da "Main" quero importar a classe "Carro", Como faço isso? Usei `require_relative "Carro"`, mas só funcionou quando estavam no mesmo pacote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O Ruby não trabalha com pacotes, e sim arquivos mesmo. Os métodos que controlam isso é o `Kernel#require` e o `Kernel#require_relative`.

O `Kernel#require` sempre pede caminhos absolutos ao caminho do arquivo, enquanto o `Kernel#require_relative` aceita caminhos relativos.

Veja o exemplo:

```
.
├── init.rb
└── modules
    ├── module_1.rb
    └── module_2.rb
```

Os arquivos:

```
# ./init.rb
puts 'init.rb called'
require './modules/module_1'

# ./modules/module_1.rb
puts 'module 1 called'
require_relative 'module_2'

# ./modules/module_2.rb
puts 'module 2 called'
```

Perceba que do `init.rb`, na raíz, para o `module_1.rb`, utilizei o `Kernel#require` com um caminho absoluto, utilizando `./modules/module_1`.

Já do `module_1` para o `module_2`, por estarem na mesma pasta, pude utilizar o `Kernel#require_relative`.

O resultado é:

```
$ ruby ./init.rb
init.rb called
module 1 called
module 2 called
```

Se quiser voltar um nível na hierarquia de pastas, basta utilizar o `../`, `../../` e assim por diante...